# PL/SQL: declare the list of numbers to be used in IN condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to define the list of ids that will be used in the cursor select?

I've tried to do it as following

```
DECLARE
  insert_user_id number := 1;
  type nt_type is table of number;
  building_num nt_type := nt_type (1,2,3,4,5);

cursor curs1 is
(
  select ID 
  from objects 
  where BUILDING_NUM in (building_num)
);
```

But what I'm getting is the following error:

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

What I found out, is that if I'll declare the list of numbers this way, it will be possible to `Loop` through them. But i don't want it. All I want is to inside of the `IN` condition of the cursor.

How can I do it?

I you want to ask me, why I just don't put the ids inside of the `IN` in cursor? My answer is: I have several cursor that use the same list ids.

**EDIT**:

According to answers below, the code looks as following:

```
create type nt_type is table of number;

DECLARE
  insert_user_id number := 1;
  building_num nt_type := nt_type (1,2,3,4,5);

cursor curs1(building_nums nt_type) is
(
  select ID 
  from objects 
  where BUILDING_NUM in (select * from table(building_nums))
);
```

Comment: A possible solution is to declare a table (or maybe a temporary table) where inserting required list of numbers, and then write the query referring to the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is that SQL query runs in SQL context and have no access to the private PL/SQL type `type nt_type is table of number;` defined in anonymous PL/SQL block. Instead you have to use SQL type. Below you'll find an example how to pass a list of numbers to a cursor. I'm positive you can adapt the idea to your problem !

```
create table so56_t (
 id number
,d varchar2(1)
);

insert into so56_t values(1, 'A');
insert into so56_t values(2, 'B');
insert into so56_t values(3, 'C');
insert into so56_t values(4, 'D');

-- SQL type required (PL/SQL type won't work)
create type num_list_t is table of number;
/

declare
  cursor cur_c(p_ids num_list_t) is
    select * from so56_t where id in (select* from table(p_ids));
begin
  declare
    v_foos constant num_list_t := num_list_t(1, 3);
    v_bars constant num_list_t := num_list_t(2, 4);

    v_r cur_c%rowtype;
  begin
    open cur_c(v_foos);
    loop
      fetch cur_c into v_r;
      exit when cur_c%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_r.d);
    end loop;
    close cur_c;

    open cur_c(v_bars);
    loop
      fetch cur_c into v_r;
      exit when cur_c%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_r.d);
    end loop;
    close cur_c;
  end;
end;
/
```

**Example run**

```
SQL> /
A
C
B
D

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Sql allowed to use only sql level collections. You have to create it. 
`create type nt_type is table of number;`

2) And query shoull look like

```
DECLARE
  building_num  nt_type  :=  nt_type  (1,2,3,4,5);
begin 
   for rec in (select 1 from dual where 1 member of building_num) loop
     null;
   end loop;
end ;


DECLARE
  building_num  nt_type  :=  nt_type  (1,2,3,4,5);
begin 
   for rec in (select 1 from dual where 1 in (select column_value from table(building_num)) loop
     null;
   end loop;
end ;
```

Also you can check your database for existing collection of number and use it.`select * from ALL_COLL_TYPES where coll_type = 'TABLE' and elem_type_name = 'NUMBER'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not exactly the same thing which I want to implement. I'm going try to explain in another words: I want to declare a variable to which I will attribute a list of ids. Then I want to do selects with `IN` condition. And in this `IN` condition I want to put this variable. My goal is to avoid for loops.

Comment: @andriy See the error:  LOCAL collection types not allowed. Make it global, see 1) and then use 2) where  BUILDING_NUM  in (select column_value from table(building_num))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use string and not table of number

```
DECLARE
  insert_user_id number := 1;
  building_nums varchar2(100) := '1,2,3,4,5';

cursor curs1 is
(
  select ID 
  from objects 
  where BUILDING_NUM  in (    
     SELECT to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR (building_nums , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
       FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (building_nums , '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  )
);
```

And variation of @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz answer

```
DECLARE
   insert_user_id   NUMBER := 1;
   -- type nt_type is table of number;
   svar             VARCHAR2 (100) := '1,2,3,4,5';
   building_nums    nt_type;
   n                NUMBER;

   CURSOR curs1
   IS
      (SELECT object_ID
         FROM all_objects
        WHERE object_id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                              FROM TABLE (building_nums)));
BEGIN
       SELECT TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (svar, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
         BULK COLLECT INTO building_nums
         FROM DUAL
   CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (svar, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

   OPEN curs1;

   LOOP
      FETCH curs1 INTO n;

      EXIT WHEN curs1%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line (n);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE curs1;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query by replacing '1,2,3,4,5' with required list of values or fetch from table.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(('1,2,3,4,5'),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(('1,2,3,4,5'), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what you have already, except that I'm not declaring a cursor.  I just wanted to post it in case it's helpful to someone.

As already mentioned, creating the table type (nt_type) first allows it to be used as desired without throwing the error:

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

With that said, here is yet another working example...

GIVEN: a table called OBJECTS containing the following data:

```
  ID BUILDING_NUM
---- ------------
1000            1
2000            2
3000            3
4000            4
5000            5
6000            6
7000            7
8000            8
9000            9
```

... and a type called nt_type

```
create type nt_type is table of number;
```

The PLSQL below loops through IDs in the OBJECTS table where BUILDING_NUM matches any in a given set (e.g., 1,2,3,4,5) and outputs some text to screen.  Of course it could do something more useful like call a procedure, or execute some SQL.

```
set serveroutput ON

DECLARE
  building_nums nt_type := nt_type (1,2,3,4,5);
BEGIN 
for i in (
   select * from objects 
   where BUILDING_NUM in (select column_value from table(building_nums))
) LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line('--do something with ID: '||i.ID||', matching building_num: '||i.BUILDING_NUM||';');
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output:

```
--do something with ID: 1000, matching building_num: 1;
--do something with ID: 2000, matching building_num: 2;
--do something with ID: 3000, matching building_num: 3;
--do something with ID: 4000, matching building_num: 4;
--do something with ID: 5000, matching building_num: 5;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```